# Small gaps on intitial masonry load, go away after window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://staging.isaidicanshout.com/isics2014/

There are small 2-3 pixel gaps between all my tiles when masonry loads the first time, but they go away after resizing the window. Any help is appreciated!

Also, is there a way to get masonry to actively re-shuffle as the window is resized, rather than waiting for the user to complete the action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up discovering that the gaps were due to rounding. My tiles were set to 50% width of the page, so when the page was an odd number of pixels, gaps were revealed.

Answer (score 0):

Guy didn't come back to answer this. Looks like he sorted it out though. For the lazy or if the link above dies.

You are going to need the imagesLoaded plugin. You should already have it if you use images as masonry + images doesn't work well with WebKit.

The magic which solves the border issue is to reload masonry once the images are loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.container').masonry({
        transitionDuration: 0,
        itemSelector: '.photo-box'
    }).imagesLoaded(function() {
        $('.container').masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
    });
});
```

Interestingly the code below doesn't work.

```
var container = $('.content');
container.imagesLoaded( function() {
    container.masonry({
        transitionDuration: 0,
        itemSelector: '.photo-box'
    });
});
```

Now we know. Well done OP for figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

What i figured out is that the window isn't re-sizing on its own for some reason hence the small gaps . This did the trick in my case .

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
 $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```